# When is iterating over a collection with for..in supported in Nim?

Tags: iteration, nim-lang

The docs for the [sets](https://nim-lang.org/docs/sets.html) module in Nim give some examples of iterating over a set via the `items` method:

```
var a = initOrderedSet[int]()
for value in [9, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2]:
  a.incl(value)
for value in a.items:
  echo "Got ", value
# --> Got 9
# --> Got 2
# --> Got 1
# --> Got 5
# --> Got 8
# --> Got 4
```

However, in the source code of sets, it appears that we can iterate over sets directly without calling `items`:

```
for item in s1:
  if item in s2: incl(result, item)
```

Is this possible because there is an `items` method for sets? In other words, if I want to design my own collection, do I need to provide an `items` implementation to support iteration with `for...in`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right, you can even create `items()` iterator implementations over types which didn't have it, thus making them iterable yourself. Here is an example for a custom object type:

```
type
  MutableState = object
    value: int

iterator items(x: var MutableState): int =
  while x.value < 10:
    yield x.value
    x.value.inc

proc test() =
  var collection = MutableState()
  collection.value = 3
  for value in collection:
    echo "Value ", value

test()
```

Comment: Hi, is there any module that I need to import?

Comment: @DrSensor the snippet of code I posted is compilable by itself, the original poster mentions using the `sets` module, so you need to add `import sets` to make the snippet compile.